# How to control range of output in tensorflow js

Tags: javascript, machine-learning, tensorflow.js

I have this model:

```
const hidden = tf.layers.dense({
  units: 8,
  inputShape: [58, 8, 8],
  activation: 'sigmoid'
});
const output = tf.layers.dense({
  units: 1,
  activation: 'softmax'
});

var model = tf.sequential({
  layers: [
  hidden,
  output
  ]
});
```

Now I want the output to be in the range -1 and 1 how do I achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The activation function is what determines the output. 'sigmoid' is good for 0 to 1 outputs and 'tanh' is good for -1 to 1, however you choose to use 'softmax' which is normally used for multi-class classification. Regardless when you make your prediction you can remap the values to another array.